# modal with items vertically centered aligned and with scroll

Tags: css

I'm using bootstrap modal, and I would like to have a list with some buttons inside the modal body with this structure:

```
    IMAGE            IMAGE        IMAGE       IMAGE
  All Options       Option1     Option2     Other Option

   IMAGE            IMAGE        IMAGE       IMAGE
   Option3         Option4      Option5       ...

   IMAGE            
   Option7
```

So the same margins between the buttons and all the list items aligned vertically aligned and with scroll because the buttons can occupy more height than the default modal height.

Do you know how to achieve that? I'm doing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/znhgdzL7/, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a max-height and an overflow to the CSS. Would that solve your issue.
It may not be the values you want, but you can adjust them accordingly.
To keep your content within the horizontal max, you will need to add the wrap property to your CSS. See the new fiddle.

```
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  max-height:50px;
  overflow-y:auto;
```

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/znhgdzL7/7/

Comment: Thanks, but in this example with more options "http://jsfiddle.net/znhgdzL7/3/" the scroll dont appears and the list items are outside the modal. Also the image is not  apeparing vertically aligned at center with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/znhgdzL7/10/

The modal can now handle many options.

here is the css:

```
img{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row > div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.categories-list {
 max-height: 400px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I also updated the html, you can just check it on the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Also, try to resize the browser of the output container, for you to check how the modal will handle the scroll.